# spell checker in android application

Tags: android

Does spellChecker same as spelling corrector? How can I implement spellChecker to check the user input for my android app in the AutoComplete text box? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a its own [Spell Checker Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html) which you can integrate into you app.
It is fairly simple to implement and the sample code is available in the sdk under SpellChecker.
While running remember to install the SampleSpellCheckerService first then the HelloSpellChecker apk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spellChecker and autocomplete text boxes are different. You can use `onGetSuggestions()`, `onGetSentenceSuggestions()` override method to implement your spellChecker application.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
  SpellCheckerSessionListener {
 public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {

 }

 public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
}